# Что значит cp35m в названии wheel на Python?

Tags: python

При попытке установить модуль .whl через pip мне выдаётся ошибка о несовместимости пакета. И это со всеми пакетами с cp35m в названии. Но модули без cp35m устанавливаются просто на ура. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

**cp** - значит, что wheel предназначен для интерпретатора CPython.

**35** - значит, что для версии 3.5 интерпретатора.

**m** - означает использование PyMalloc для управления памятью.

Если в названии файла после символов `cp35m` идёт сразу расширение `.whl`, значит пакет кроссплатформенный, и тогда остаётся только убедиться, что вы используете именно Python 3.5. Сделать это можно запуском интерпретатора с ключом `-V`.

Если же в имени файла есть и другие символы, типа `win_amd64`, то он предназначен для конкретной операционной системы определённой разрядности.